# whereHas not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

I am trying to get all `Shop`s that have one of `$item_ids = array('1', '17');`.

However, the code below is not doing that as I expected it to - it just hands me all the shops.

```
$shops = Shop::whereHas('items', function($query) use ($item_ids) {

                    $query->where('items.id', '=', $item_ids[0]);

                    foreach(array_slice($item_ids, 1) as $item_id) {
                        $query->orWhere('items.id', '=', $item_id);
                    }
                })
                ->get(array('shops.id', 'shops.shop_name', 'shops.lat', 'shops.lng'));
```

I do I only get the `Shop`s with one of the specified `Item`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather use:

```
$shops = Shop::whereHas('items', function($query) use ($item_ids) {    
     $query->whereIn('id', $items_ids);
})->get();
```

or

```
$shops = Shop::whereHas('items', function($query) use ($item_ids) {    
     $query->whereIn('id', $items_ids);
})->select('shops.id', 'shops.shop_name', 'shops.lat', 'shops.lng')->get();
```